# group dublicates without linq vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sorting, grouping

Test is a list of object,  I ordered and grouped them by the "Total" property as this:

```
Dim duplicates = test.GroupBy(Function(i) i.Total) _
                            .Where(Function(x) x.Count() > 1) _
                            .[Select](Function(x) x).ToList
```

After doing dome test I found that with large list it get  too much memory, so I'd like to do it in place(I searched on S.O. and web, and as I understood, Linq is not the way for in place way.)
Any advice?

Comment: that depends on how u define your 'test' object. IF you already test as List, for sure it is slow. If is IQuery instead of IList then it will be different story

Comment: You are right, Linq was not the way. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved implementing Icompare interface

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Microsoft docs about it is pretty exaustive.